# Chain rules for Dini Derivative

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Could someone provides some references for the chain rule concerning Dini derivatives. For example, let $f(\cdot) \in \mathcal{C}^1\left( \mathbb{R} ; \mathbb{R}\right)$, and $g(\cdot) \in \mathcal{C}\left( \mathbb{R} ; \mathbb{R}\right)$ where $D^+g(x)$ is finite. Can we use chain rule for $D^+ \left( f\circ g \right)(x) = D^+ f \left( g (x) \right)$ like  $D^+ \left( f\circ g \right)(x) = \dfrac{\mathsf{d}f(g(x))}{\mathsf{d}g(x)}$$D^+g(x)$ ? Furthermore, what about functions with more general structures defined on vector space?

Comment: Let $g = x \sin^2(1/x)$. And $f(y) = -y$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

[Lemma 4](http://mia.ele-math.com/05-02/Spherically-symmetric-functions-with-a-convex-second-derivative-and-applications-to-extremal-probabilistic-problems) states the following:

> Let $f(t)=u(u_1(t))u_2(t)+u_3(t)$ for all $t\in[a,b)$, where function $u$ is
>   nondecreasing on $[a,b)$, function $u_1$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b)$,
>   function $u_2$ is nonnegative on $[a,b)$, and $\forall i\in\{1,2,3\}$
>   $\exists(u_i)'_+(a)\in\R$. Then
>   $$D_+f(a)\ge u(u_1(a))(u_2)'_+(a)+(u_3)'_+(a);$$
>   moreover, if $(D_+u)(u_1(a))<\infty$ or $(u_1)'_+(a)u_2(a)>0$, then
>   $$D_+f(a)=(D_+u)(u_1(a))(u_1)'_+(a)u_2(a)+u(u_1(a))(u_2)'_+(a)+(u_3)'_+(a).$$

Here, $f'_+(t):=\lim_{s\downarrow t}\frac{f(s)-f(t)}{s-t}$.

As noted in that paper, "This is proved essentially the same way as for usual derivatives", provided appropriate conditions on monotonicity and/or sign patterns; cf. the comment by Willie Wong.

As for generalizations to functions defined on a vector space, directional Dini derivatives immediately reduce to those over $\R$. In fact, the cited paper deals with functions on a Hilbert space.